# Display Issue- Validation occurs in page load

Tags: validation, struts2

Validation occurs while page loading. Error messages are displayed as page loads.

My index.jsp looks like

```
<body>
Employee Information : 
   <s:form action="empinfo" method="post">
      <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" size="20" />
      <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" size="20" />
      <s:select name="gender" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select Gender"
     label="gender" list="#{'1':'Male','2':'Female'}" />

      <s:textfield name="email" label="Email" size="20" />
      <s:textfield name="phone" label="Phone_Number" size="20" />
      <s:submit name="submit" label="Login" align="center" />  
   </s:form>
</body>
```

Action class(Employee.java)

```
public String execute() 
   {
       return SUCCESS;
   }
```

Validation File Employee-validation.xml:

```
 <field name="name">
      <field-validator type="requiredstring">
         <message>
            The name is required.
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>

   <field name="age">
      <field-validator type="required">
         <message>
            The age is required.
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>
```

And struts.xml file as:

```
<action name="empinfo" 
         class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.Employee"
         method="execute">
         <result name="init">/index.jsp</result>   
         <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
         <result name="success">/Edit.jsp</result>
      </action>
```

What shoud i do to validate the form once i click submit?? is there any configuration needed for struts.xml file for this?

Comment: Please read about Struts2 validation: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/validation.html.

Comment: If the validation occurs what else do you need?

Comment: Need to display the captured values in the next page.

Comment: What do you mean the next page?

Comment: Results in Edit.jsp page.

Comment: How would you like to display them as textfields or text?

Comment: Edit.jsp code is   Employee Information is captured successfully.<br/>
   Name : <s:property value="name"/> <br/>
   Age : <s:property value="age"/> <br/>
   Gender : <s:property value="gender"/> <br/>
   Email: <s:property value="email"/> <br/>
   Phone Number: <s:property value="phone"/> <br/>

Comment: you can only display the values after the validation was successful or eliminate the validation.

Comment: My problem is the validation occurs on page load itself.. enen befor i enter values and click submit.

Comment: Hi, I faced similar problem but in my case it was only related to action call, I was calling an bussiness logic action instead of calling the navigation action

Answer (score 0):

write validation code in action class. you are using struts2 so you can do this like below.

```
<action name="empinfo" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.Employee" method="formSubmit">
   <result name="init">/index.jsp</result>   
   <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
   <result name="success">/Edit.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

in Employee.java

```
  public String validateFormSubmit() 
  {
    if(age.equals(null)){
     //display msg feild is required
    }

    if(name.equals(null)){
     //display msg feild is required
    }
  }

public String formSubmit() 
   {
       return SUCCESS;
   }
```